# How to save a field from another model to a variable NOT A FIELD

Tags: django, django-models, reference

I have a model called Actual:

```
# Actual parts table
class Actual(models.Model):
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Vendor name", related_name="actualvendor")       
    number = models.CharField("External part number", max_length=32, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)     
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)                                     
    pq = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=1)                                                           
    mrrp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)     
    # Model metadata
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["vendor", "number"]
        verbose_name_plural = "actual external parts"
    # Display below in admin 
    def __str__(self): 
       return f"{self.number}"
```

I also have another model called Offer:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    sync_id = models.ForeignKey(Sync, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Internal part number", related_name="part")
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, default=0)   
    moq = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=1)                                              
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=OFFERSTATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    actual = models.OneToOneField(Actual, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Display something in admin
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Offer {self.id} for {self.sync_id}"

    # Calculate the price
    def price(self):
        return self.actual.mrrp * (1-self.discount)
```

I am trying to calculate the 'price' in the 'Offer' model using 'mrrp' but 'mrrp' is from the 'Actual' model.

I am able to do so with the code I've attached but as you can see in the django admin, the 'actual' shows up as a field. I don't want it to appear as a field. I just want 'actual' to be a variable that is equal to the value of 'mrrp'. That way I can use it to calculate the price.
[image: Django admin view of adding an Offer]

Is there another way to reference fields from another model? Surely fields aren't the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a property decorator. I had the right idea but did not place a property decorator on top of the function that calculates the price. Use a property decorator to display the data as you would a field in Django.

I added the below to the bottom of my model:

```
    @property
    def price(self):
        return self.actual.mrrp * (1-self.discount)
```